# Getting 'device not configured' error when trying to run Go backend server

Tags: go, configuration, go-gorm

Terminal:

```
solomonng@Solomons-MBP cornerstone-backend % brew services start postgresql@13 Service postgresql@13 already started, use brew services restart postgresql@13 to restart. solomonng@Solomons-MBP cornerstone-backend % make run Running server in development mode... Starting service device not configured

solomonng@Solomons-MBP cornerstone-backend % export GO_ENV=development && reflex -d none -r '.go$$' -s go run ./cmd/server/main.go Starting service device not configured
```

env.development.local:

```
SERVER_PORT=8000

DB_HOSTNAME=/tmp
DB_PORT=5432
DB_NAME=aac_development
DB_USERNAME=solomonng
DB_PASSWORD=
DB_SSLMODE=
```

file in

```
./cmd/server/main.go
```

:

```
package vms

import (
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "gorm.io/gorm/clause"

    "gitlab.com/nuscvwo/aac/aac-backend/internal/errors/externalerrors"
    "gitlab.com/nuscvwo/aac/aac-backend/internal/metadata"
    "gitlab.com/nuscvwo/aac/aac-backend/pkg/enums"
    "gitlab.com/nuscvwo/aac/aac-backend/pkg/nullable"
    "gitlab.com/nuscvwo/aac/aac-backend/pkg/userstamps"
)

type Organisation struct {
    metadata.Model
    userstamps.StampModel

    Name             nullable.String `gorm:"not null"`
    OrganisationType nullable.Int    `gorm:"not null"`

    Staffs      []Staff      `gorm:"constraint:OnDelete:CASCADE"`
    Students    []Student    `gorm:"constraint:OnDelete:CASCADE"`
    Deployments []Deployment `gorm:"constraint:OnDelete:CASCADE"`
}

func (Organisation) TableName() string {
    return "vms_organisations"
}

const (
    OrgModelName    = "organisation"
    ErrOrgNameEmpty = "Organisation name must not be empty"
    ErrOrgTypeEmpty = "Organisation type must not be empty"
)

func (org *Organisation) Validate() error {
    // TODO: validation
    if !org.Name.Valid {
        return &externalerrors.ValidationError{Message: ErrOrgNameEmpty}
    }
    return nil
}

func (org *Organisation) ValidateMustBeNew() error {
    if org.ID.Valid {
        return &externalerrors.CreateExistingRecordError{
            Model:   OrgModelName,
            ModelID: org.ID.ValueOrZero(),
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func (org *Organisation) ensureOrganisationIsNewOrSame(originalID nullable.Int) error {
    if !org.ID.Valid {
        return org.ValidateMustBeNew()
    }
    if org.ID != originalID {
        return externalerrors.ValidationErrorRecordChanged(
            OrgModelName,
            originalID.ValueOrZero(),
            org.ID.ValueOrZero(),
        )
    }
    return nil
}

func (org *Organisation) ValidateAssociations(original *Organisation) error {
    if err := org.ensureOrganisationIsNewOrSame(original.ID); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func (org *Organisation) PruneOldAssociations(original *Organisation, tx *gorm.DB) error {
    return nil
}

func (org *Organisation) Create(tx *gorm.DB) error {
    return tx.Create(org).Error
}

func (org *Organisation) Update(tx *gorm.DB) error {
    return tx.Omit(clause.Associations).Updates(org).Error
}

func (org *Organisation) Delete(tx *gorm.DB) error {
    return tx.Delete(org).Error
}

func (org *Organisation) BeforeCreate(tx *gorm.DB) error {
    if err := org.validateEnums(tx); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return org.Validate()
}

func (org *Organisation) BeforeUpdate(tx *gorm.DB) error {
    if err := org.validateEnums(tx); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return org.Validate()
}

func (org *Organisation) validateEnums(tx *gorm.DB) error {
    orgTypeEnum := enums.OrganisationType(org.OrganisationType.ValueOrZero())
    if err := orgTypeEnum.ValidateEnum(tx); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Ive been getting "device not configured" and unable to run the go backend server, although the the configuration file should be consistent with the documentation's instructions, and started the database, which is working fine. Any ideas as to what might be wrong? Help is greatly appreciated in this moment of desperation, thank you in advance!